# Is it possible to pass custom object into SpringBoot's endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot project and in an every endpoint's the first call is parsing a request header into a POJO object. making sure required headers are set. Is it possible "to teach" SpringBoot to be able to provide custom object in endpoints?

```java
class CommonHeader {

    private String callerId;
    private String systemId;
    ....

    public static CommonHeader parseCommonHeader(Map<String, String> map) {
        CommonHeader header = new CommonHeader();
        header.setCallerId(map.get("x-caller-id"));
        .....
        return header;
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("/columnConfigs")
Response getColumnConfig(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
    CommonHeader commonHeader = parseCommonHeader(headers);
    ....
}

@Path("/other")
Response getColumnConfig(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
    CommonHeader commonHeader = parseCommonHeader(headers);
    ....
}
```

I would like to be able to simplify the following code into:

```java
@Path("/columnConfigs")
Response getColumnConfig(CommonHeader commonHeader) {
    ....
}

@Path("/other")
Response getColumnConfig(CommonHeader commonHeader) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to map all headers to that object, or to parse a single header only? (e.g. you have a header that contains a JSON object)

Comment: CommonHeader is a POJO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for some solution for this, that is, bind headers to an object of our definition. I found a good technique here: [Using Custom Data Binders in SpringMVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder#binding-domain-objects)

What you have to do in a nutshell are these, apart from the already created `CommonHeader` class:

1. Define an annotation, say `@MyHeaders` (with `@Retention( RUNTIME )` and `@Target( PARAMETER )`)

```
@Retention( RUNTIME )
@Target( PARAMETER )
public @interface MyHeaders {}
```

2. Create an implementation of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, say `MyHeadersResolver`. This will map the headers from the request into an instance of `CommonHeader` and return it.

```
@Override
    public boolean supportsParameter( MethodParameter methodParameter ){
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation( MyHeaders.class ) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument( MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavc, NativeWebRequest req, WebDataBinderFactory wdbf ) throws Exception{
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req.getNativeRequest();
        
        CommonHeader h = new CommonHeader();
        Collections.list( request.getHeaderNames() ).forEach( header -> {
            switch( header.toLowerCase() ) {
                //Set values into CommonHeader instance
            }
        });
        
        return h;
    }
```

3. Declare this to SpringMVC as an argument resolver in a class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`, like this:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers( List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers ) {
    resolvers.add( new MyHeadersResolver() );
}
```

4. Your controller method signature will now look like this:

```
Response getColumnConfig( @MyHeaders CommonHeader commonHeader )
```

Comment: Thanks! That works well and looks elegant.

Comment: Happy to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Define `CommonHeader` to extend `Map<String, String>`:

```
@RequestHeader
public interface CommonHeader extends Map<String, String> {
}
```

Comment: This is OK but `@RequestHeader` seems to be a method parameter level annotation and not applicable to a class. So, define the class without the annotation and apply the annotation against the method param. **However,** if we are doing this, we can as well use the inbuilt `HttpHeaders` of SpringMVC.